# clutch flywheel

Tags: conversion, flywheel

i am looking for a clutch flywheel for a ford fusion, the ford part is out of my price range and was looking for an after market part priced more reasonable and can not find anything.it is an 8E5Z-6375A i can find no cross ref.

Comment: Year and engine if the fusion?

Comment: Why have you tagged this question as "conversion?" Seems like you're asking about replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Generally with parts like this you will find only OEM parts and possible some high-performance units, which are likely more expensive than the OEM ones.

Have you checked local junkyards or EBAY for a used one?

Comment: junkyards - exactly plus 1